# about oshi-core, I use m1(macbook air)

Tags: java

I have two projects, one project use oshi to get my cpu infomation, and it works well.

```
public class MyTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
    HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();
    CentralProcessor cpu = hal.getProcessor();
    System.out.println("cpu.getLogicalProcessorCount(): " + cpu.getLogicalProcessorCount());
    System.out.println("cpu.getCurrentFreq(): " + cpu.getCurrentFreq());
    System.out.println("hal.getMemory(): " + hal.getMemory());

}
```

But the other project use oshi to get my cpu info, almost the same code, but it throws a exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/herrhu/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7537516652503870093.tmp: dlopen(/Users/herrhu/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7537516652503870093.tmp, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/herrhu/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7537516652503870093.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
/Users/herrhu/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7537516652503870093.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1950)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1832)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:811)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1088)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1018)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:988)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:195)
at com.sun.jna.platform.mac.SystemB.<clinit>(SystemB.java:40)
at oshi.util.platform.mac.SysctlUtil.sysctl(SysctlUtil.java:61)
at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacCentralProcessor.initProcessorCounts(MacCentralProcessor.java:128)
at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractCentralProcessor.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:74)
at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacCentralProcessor.<init>(MacCentralProcessor.java:61)
at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacHardwareAbstractionLayer.createProcessor(MacHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:60)
at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:87)
at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.getProcessor(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:68)
at com.clougence.cloudcanal.sidecar.shell.OshiTest2.main(OshiTest2.java:28)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I don't know why the same code in diffrent project has different results. And the dependencies in two projects is same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlBov.png)